# bitcoin wallet error

Tags: wallet, error

I have a problem I am unable to start my miners and unable to open my bitcoin wallet. when I try to open wallet I get
Program:C:\program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe 
File:chain.cpp,Line96

Expression: pindxWalk->pprev

Please can anyone help me

Thank you 
brenerj

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7992 also https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9170 and https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9001 IRC log of similar issue: https://botbot.me/freenode/bitcoin-core-dev/2016-06-26/?msg=68636369&page=1

Comment: I think a bunch of people have had this problem, and so far nobody's come up with anything better than deleting the blockchain and resyncing.